# Wordpress cannot access MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My wordpress blog, hosted on my `IIS 7.5 Server`, suddenly lost his connection to localhost `MySQL Database` with no apparent reason.
Both public and `wp-admin` links

Both public and wp-admin links throw an `"Error establishing a database connection"` exception.

I have successfully verified host name, user name and password opening a new ODBC connection with `MySQL ODBC 5.3` Unicode Driver entering the credentials defined under `DB_HOST`, `DB_USER` and `DB_PASSWORD` at `wp_config.php`.

I've also verified database is not corrupted since I can successfully browse the database from `MySQL Workbench 6.3`

`IIS 7.5 application pool` is started.

I have tested wordpress connection with next code:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', '(my user name)', '(my password)');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

which throws next result:

> Could not connect: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No
>   such host is known.

If I change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` the code just returns

> 'Could not connect:'

and no error is displayed.

Any help will be apreciated

Comment: Have you checked the DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD in your wp-config.php?

Comment: Yes, I haven't changed this file for long, but anyway I could successfully open a ODBC connection to MySQL with the same data stored on on my wp-config.php

Comment: Are you working on live or local?

Comment: Do one thing `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` in your wp-config.php file then check what error are displayed.

Comment: Great Kausha!! it now works and displays a Notice about add_custom_background obsolet since versión 3.4. I should use add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $args ) instead.